# Storing a pointer to a callback with arguments function in c

Tags: c, function, pointers, callback, arguments

I am trying to store a reference (I think that's what it is) to a call back for local use later on. The code I have tried is shown below.

```
void (Port4Task)(uint8_t);   // user function
void BumpInt_Init(void(*task)(uint8_t)){
  Port4Task = task();
```

Unfortunately when I try this I get an error "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" and "too few arguments in function call". I have also tried,

```
uint8_t value;
void (Port4Task)(uint8_t);   // user function
void BumpInt_Init(void(*task)(uint8_t)){
  Port4Task = task(value);
```

But I still get the error "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". If there are any suggestions, explanations or clarifications as to what I should be doing, what I'm doing wrong or how I could be doing things better I would really appreciate hearing from the community.

Thanks
Kas

I have also tried

```
void (Port4Task)();   // user function
void BumpInt_Init(void(*task)(uint8_t)){
Port4Task = task;
```

And

```
void (Port4Task)(uint8_t);   // user function
void BumpInt_Init(void(*task)(uint8_t)){
Port4Task = task;
```

Using this I still get the lvalue error mentioned above. This was in fact my first attempt.

Comment: void (Port4Task)(uint8_t);   // user function
    void BumpInt_Init(void(*task)(uint8_t)){
      Port4Task = task;

Using this I still get the lvalue error mentioned above. This was in fact my first attempt.

Comment: `void (*Port4Task)(uint8_t); `

Comment: @StoryTeller's edit defines your global as a '*pointer* to a function', which is what you want.  In addition, you need to assign a pointer to that global, that means assigning `task` without *calling* it.  I.e., you also need to change `Port4Task = task; //Store a pointer to task, don't call it`

Comment: Thank you StoryTeller, that worked just fine. Funny thing is I did have the * to start with but I guess when I had a warning (I didnt have the uint8_t as an argument at first) I must have removed it for some reason.